# pvrect() rectangles in horizontal dendrogram (R)

Tags: r, hierarchical-clustering, dendrogram, dendextend, pvclust

I am trying to draw rectangles around clusters in a **horizontal** dendrogram. 
This works fine as long as I only cut the tree manually, e.g.

```
dend<-as.dendrogram(hc)
plot(dend, horiz=T)
rect.dendrogram(dend, 3)
```

However, I also want to highlight clusters found significant by `pvlust()`, which so far I can only accomplish for a **vertical** dendrogram with `pvrect()`.

I believe there is more to be done with the `rect.dendrogram()` function, but I don't understand which values I need to get from `pvclust()` and where to put those.

Can anyone provide a solution to this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure. In the meantime, I suggest you take a look at this: http://talgalili.github.io/dendextend/articles/dendextend.html#pvclust-1
If you end up writing up a solution, please make a code submission to dendextend:
https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend